# How do I save iBooks pdfs to an external hard drive?

Tags: ipad, books

How do I save all of my iBooks pdfs, located on my iPad2, to an external hard drive?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.   What computer are you using to connect to the drive and what operating system runs there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to post the church boy answer, but if you jailbreak your device, you will have full access to the file system.

There is probably a legitimate way to do this without jailbreaking, but having jailbroken devices myself, I would simply enable SSH (the root password is `alpine`, which you should change immediately) and either `rsync` or `scp` the files to your external hard drive volume (which in my case is mounted on a Mac Mini (also running `sshd`).  The hard drive will be mounted in `/Volumes`.

I forget the exact path to your Camera Roll, but the main directory you are looking for containing the photos and videos is `DCIM`.

If your external drive is a Windows computer, then there are also tools in Cydia that make file sharing with Windows a breeze.  Or if you're like me and have to run Cygwin with `sshd` on all of your Windows boxes, the same rules as above would apply, but the path to the external drive would be `/cygdrive/[drive letter]`.

If you are on a Mac and enable SSH to your iPad, just do the following in Terminal on your Mac (if it is a Mac):

```
cd /Volumes/[external drive]/[folder to store images]
scp root@[iPad IP address]:/path/to/DCIM/* .
```

It would be a good idea to use `screen` for this job so that it doesn't fail from a broken pipe in case you have a lot of images.  If you want to go that route, you could do something like this `screen -LS image.copy` which would put you in a new shell session.  Then run the commands above, and detach from the session with `Ctrl+A-D`.  This lets the process run in the background.  If you want to come back later and check the progress, run `screen -x image.copy`.

If you are going to do something like this, you should make sure that you are hooked up to power and don't have auto-lock set, or else it will end your session prematurely.

This may be a horrible answer, but I always default to command line, because it never fails me.